# What is the exit code after a php exception?

Tags: php

I'm working with a program that runs a command-line PHP script. The PHP script has been throwing exceptions, but the program has been seeing exit code 0 (and not checking for exceptions).

- Do PHP scripts actually return a different exit code and the program is just getting the wrong exit code somehow?
- Or do they really return exit code 0 with an exception?
- Or do they not return an exit code at all?

Comment: Why don't you check that on your own with a simple example script?

Comment: The manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php states: *"The status 0 is used to terminate the program **successfully.**"* - So why would an exception be of any use?

Comment: @NicoHaase A simple script like what? If you have an idea, please just post an answer like Philipp did. I made this question because I'm at the end of my rope and don't know what to do.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner The script was throwing exceptions because it wasn't terminating successfully

Comment: @Miryafa Oh, I see. 10-4 :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case of a exception, the return status code is 255. You could simply test this inside your bash with a simple script.

exc.php

```
<?php throw new Exception();
```

and run

```
php exc.php
echo $? //prints 255
```

However, you should keep in mind, this is only valid, if you don't define your own exception handler. In case you define your own handler, you have to return the return code manually inside the exception handler.

exc2.php

```
<?php
set_exception_handler(function() {});
throw new Exception();
```

returns status code `0`. If you want an status code, use `exit`

```
<?php
set_exception_handler(function() {
    exit(42);
});
throw new Exception("","","");
```

now the script returns the status code `42`